# How to generate java model classes without annotations using openapi-generator-maven-plugin/ swagger?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, yaml, swagger, swagger-codegen

I want to generate java model classes from yaml file without annotations in generating classes.
How it is possible to generate? I tried multiple ways but not able to generate model classes without annotations. Always containing annotations in generating classes.

```
<plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
                <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>5.1.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/pesttore.yml</inputSpec>
                            <modelPackage>com.my.path.to.api</modelPackage>
                            <generatorName>java</generatorName>
                            <generateApis>false</generateApis>
                            <generateModels>true</generateModels>
                            <generateModelDocumentation>false</generateModelDocumentation>
                            <generateModelTests>false</generateModelTests>
                            <apisToGenerate>false</apisToGenerate>
                            <withXml>false</withXml>
                        <!--<library>resttemplate</library> --> 
                            <configOptions>
                                <sourceFolder>src/main/java</sourceFolder>
                                <serializableModel>true</serializableModel>
                                <dateLibrary>java8</dateLibrary>
                                <annotationLibrary>none</annotationLibrary>
                                <serializationLibrary>jsonb</serializationLibrary>
                                <additionalModelTypeAnnotations>null</additionalModelTypeAnnotations>
                            <documentationProvider>none</documentationProvider>
                            <additional-properties>generateModelBuilders=true,useJackson=false,sortParamsByRequiredFlag=false,useJacksonJsonIgnoreUnknownProperties=false</additional-properties>
                            </configOptions>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

This was added in version [5.4.0](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/releases/tag/v5.4.0) in [this PR](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/pull/11258). You'll need to update your plugin version.